# How to distinct the result from elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, distinct

hi can i check what the code for the distinct value results on elasticsearch.

- Result 1: Blue
- Result 2: Red
- Result 3: Blue
- Result 4: Black
- Result 5: White
- Result 6: Blue
- Result 7: Green
- Result 8: Red
- Result 9: Pink

instead of 9 results,

i wish to get only 6 results only, by right it should show Blue, Red, Black, White, Green, Pink

for example the results currently is like that for the code but it display 9 results

```
Get /color/_search
{
  "aggs": {
     "color_filter" : { 
        "terms": {
            "field": "color.keyword"
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using "terms" aggregation which takes multiple values. Try using "term" like this

```
{
  "aggs": {
     "color_filter" : { 
        "term": {
            "field": "color.keyword"
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: i try using term, it reply "type": "named_object_not_found_exception", "reason":"[4:15] unable to parse BaseAgregationBuilder with name [term]: parser not found"

Comment: Sorry I thought it was a Query. "terms" is correct for aggregations. I think you are checking the hits in the response. Hits will always contain each documents individually. You have to check aggregations in the response that will group the unique documents in your case.

Comment: If you don't want hits in the response u have to add "size": 0 to the request so that you will only get aggregation response